# Implement policies in .net core view custom Access Denied views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm building an application where I'm trying to use policies to control my users access.

If they've created an account, they then need to get approved by an admin. So they will be met by my custom AccessDenied.cshtml view at first login. This part works great:

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().
            RequireAuthenticatedUser().
            RequireRole("AuthenticatedUser").
            Build();
            options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            options.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());                

        }).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
```

Now I need another Filter, which checks on a different set of roles, and returns another, custom made "AccessDenied" view.

Is this possible somehow? I know I can just insert another RequireRole("role"), but then they'll be met with the same access denied page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hitting several deadends, I finally found an acceptable way of solving this.
It took several steps, but in case anyone else ever needs this, I'll just document what I did:

1.

Add both roles to your policy in the startup file, and add a custom path to accessdenied ABOVE your .Addmvc call:

```
services.PostConfigure<CookieAuthenticationOptions>(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme,
            opt =>
            {
                opt.AccessDeniedPath = $"/Home/AccessDeniedCustom";
            });

 services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().
            RequireAuthenticatedUser().
            RequireRole("AuthenticatedUser").
            RequireRole("Your2ndRole").
                Build();
            options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            options.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
        }).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
```

2. Now we'll get our custom access denied view if we either role, but that's still only 1 access denied page for both of the roles.

We'll go to our AccessDeniedCustom view, and use Razor syntax to render the view. Basically I have two full views in the view file, and I use something along the following to decide which to render:

```
@{
ViewData["Title"] = "AccessDeniedCustom";
var user = Context.User;
}

@if (!user.IsInRole("AuthenticatedUser")){ //Show some html }
else{ //show some different html}
```

Make sure to put an [AllowAnonymous] on your new, custom Access Denied view, otherwise you wont get very far.